# How to ignore the rest of the line in Buffered Reader after ' ', or a specific character' on a line?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, skip

I have to ignore rest of the input line after I have read the necessary digits, using `BufferedReader`

So if the input is:

```
3 // not important 
18 //same
2 // okay
```

etc. I don't want to read from ' ' until the end of the line.

I have only found the method skip, but this seems to skip the whole line.

Comment: You read the whole line, then you take the part you need from it. Or you use a `Scanner` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = br.readLine().split(" ")[0];
```

Basically this reads a line and split it into words separated by ' ' and select the first one.

Hope this serves the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This achives what you are after, I think.

```
BufferedReader reader; //Initialize it 
String line = reader.readLine();
return line.substring( line.indexOf( CHAR HERE ) );
```